# My USB is basically gone after 'diskutil zeroDisk /dev/disk2'. What do I do?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, disk-utility, usb, disk-format

My USB was screwed up after I did something wrong while using bootcamp (don't remember the details).

I did a bunch of stuff but it doesn't really matter as here's the current situation:

My USB won't show up on the desktop. It's in Disk Utility, with the main disk seeming normal and WinInstall blanked out and saying 'Not Mounted'. In previous attempts, whenever I tried to erase or mount it, the usb would disappear. I do not know what I should do anymore. It has currently disappeared again and I'm reinserting the USB to get it back up in Disk Utility

(Please don't mention Finder>Preferences>External Disks because I checked it already)

(First Aid also fails to do anything with the WinInstall volume, but it succeeds in the general VenderCo disk that's above it.)

I need to format the WinInstall volume but do not need the files on this USB to be recovered, although if it were possible it would be great.

Comment: It would be far better if you reduced your post to simply the salient points, with a single answerable question. I've read this twice & I cannot tell what you need.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry for the inconvenience. I quickly deleted most of the backstory and stuff. Now it's just describing my current situation. What I  need is advice on how to erase and format the disk to MD-DOS without it failing (and then somehow disappearing)

Comment: Have you tried to format the top level of the stick in Disk Utility, the VendorCo? Format: MS-DOS(FAT) Scheme: Master Boot Record.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll try that right now. Wait a few minutes

Comment: @Tetsujin Before I begin, is it possible that you tell me the alternative of that for 'terminal'. Unfortunately, the USB started the disappearing after 5 minutes routine again (It pretends to not be plugged in and won't appear in terminal, system info etc.). Before the 5 minute mark, it won't show on Disk Utility and has a process (fsck_exFat) running in activity monitor.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd just like to say I'm sorry that my USB is so spontaneous. It just appeared on the desktop again. Hopefully, I can fix everything before it goes away. Please forgive my spamming

Comment: @Tetsujin Welp, the erase process for VenderCo failed.

Comment: Bin it then & get a new one. They're not worth fighting once they start to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much going on with your operating system and in the comments, I would take the USB drive to another computer to test it. Then you can have possibly two follow on questions.

One to address erasing a USB or knowing it is flakey.

A second question where you ask how to get your Mac in a desired state. (Like how to erase install macOS.)

Comment: It's fixed... somehow. By now, I don't understand what's going on. I took it to my PC again and usually it would give an error saying 'Please insert a disk into the Removable Disk (J:)' but I don't know how, it worked this time and opened. I formatted the USB. And now we'll never know what was going on that made it fix itself.

Comment: So in the end, you're technically correct even though it all happened because of a fluke XD

Comment: @ForestDan wow - I’ve seen so many strange things - this is one I’ve seen quite often every few years.